# How do I make GTK+ 3.0 signal handler work on Windows 10 using MSYS2 and Mingw-W64?

Tags: c, windows, gtk3, glade, msys2

This is the code for my application `part1.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtkx.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *fixed1;
GtkWidget *button1;
GtkWidget *label1;
GtkBuilder *builder;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("part1.glade");

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window"));

    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    fixed1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "fixed1"));
    button1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button1"));
    label1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "label1"));

    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void on_button1_clicked(GtkButton *b)
{
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label1), (const gchar*)"Hello World!");
}
```

This is the `part1.glade` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.0"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <property name="default_width">640</property>
    <property name="default_height">480</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed" id="fixed1">
        <property name="width_request">640</property>
        <property name="height_request">480</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="width_request">190</property>
            <property name="height_request">20</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">7</property>
            <property name="y">8</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">20</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_button1_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">136</property>
            <property name="y">6</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

To compile the program on Windows 10 I use MSYS2 and Mingw-W64:
I type `` gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` part1.c -o part1.exe `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -lm ``
The option `-rdynamic` is not available on Windows and the problem I'm having is that when I click the button, nothing happens.
The following error is displayed on MSYS2:

```
(part1.exe:608): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:26:19.469: Could not find signal handler 'on_button1_clicked'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?
```

What should I do for the `on_button1_clicked` signal handler to work on Windows 10? The same code runs without a flaw on Linux when compiled with `-rdynamic` but this option is not available on Windows. What should I do here?

Comment: I think `static void on_button1_clicked` has worked for me without `-rdynamic`.

Comment: I tried ```static void on_button1_clicked```, it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to declare the function `void on_button1_clicked(GtkButton *b)` as `G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_button1_clicked(GtkButton *b)`
This should do the trick!

CREDIT:http://blog.latepaul.com/glade-gtk-on-windows-with-msys2

Comment: I have had exactly the same issue.  This answer solved it!